# Sorting a list of dates into an array of unique years/months/days

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, date, datetime

I have been struggling with this for a while now so I have decided to ask for help.

I need to convert a list of dates like this:

```
2019-09-17,
2019-09-16,
2018-08-15,
2017-08-14
```

and output them as a nested list of unique years/months/days:

- 2019

  - 09

    - 17
    - 16
- 2018

  - 08

    - 15
- 2017

  - 08

    - 14

```
$dates = wp_list_pluck( $queriedFiles->posts, 'post_date' );

$cleanDates = array();

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $createDate = new DateTime($date);
    $date = $createDate->format('Y-m-d');
    array_push($cleanDates, $date);
}
$uniqueDates = array_unique($cleanDates);

$years = array();

$properDates = array();
foreach ($uniqueDates as $date) {
    $createDate = new DateTime($date);
    $strippedYear = $createDate->format('Y');
    $strippedMonth = $createDate->format('m');
    $strippedDay = $createDate->format('d');

    $thisDate = array('year' => $strippedYear, 'month'=>$strippedMonth, 'day'=>$strippedDay);

    array_push($years, $strippedYear);
    array_push($properDates, $thisDate);
}
```

I am hoping to end up with a multidimensional array that I can loop through to get the years/months/days

Any help you guys could offer would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode`. Something like this:

```
$dates = ['2019-09-17', '2019-09-16', '2018-08-15', '2017-08-14'];

$result = [];

foreach($dates as $date) {
    $dateParts = explode('-', $date);
    $result[$dateParts[0]][$dateParts[1]][] = $dateParts[2];
}
```

will produce

```
array(3) {
  [2019]=>
  array(1) {
    ["09"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "17"
      [1]=>
      string(2) "16"
    }
  }
  [2018]=>
  array(1) {
    ["08"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "15"
    }
  }
  [2017]=>
  array(1) {
    ["08"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "14"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to sort you can simply sort like this:

```
foreach($result as &$e){
    ksort($e);
    foreach($e as &$t){
        asort($t);
    }
}

ksort($result);
```

`ksort`(ascending) or `krsort`(descending) will sort by keys, and `sort`(ascending) or `rsort`(descending) will sort by values;

Comment: If you want to sort the output, you should only call `sort()` once BEFORE iterating the data.  For uniqueness, `$result[$dateParts[0]][$dateParts[1]][$dateParts[2]] = $dateParts[2];`